# update model value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is a code snipped of view and controller. Here what I want just click on save button I mean

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-r15" type="button"
 ng-click="$parent.saveReleaseNotes(latestReleaseNotes,isEditabel);$apply()"
 ng-disabled="formSubmitted" value="{{saveButton}}" />
```

A request will be sent to server and when get success then  tag must be hidden and

tag will show but not working

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix mr-b25 bdr-b">
    <h6 class="mr-tb20">Release Notes &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a ng-if="isEditabel == false" href="" ng-click="$parent.isEditabel = true"
        class="f-14 semi-bold mr-l15"> Edit </a>
    </h6>
</div>
<p ng-show="!isEditabel" class="form-control-static f-14">{{latestReleaseNotes}}</p>


<div ng-show="isEditabel">
    <textarea ng-model="latestReleaseNotes" rows="3" columns="15"
    class="form-control" ng-disabled="formSubmitting"></textarea>
    <br /> <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-r15" type="button"
    ng-click="$parent.saveReleaseNotes(latestReleaseNotes,isEditabel);$apply()"
    ng-disabled="formSubmitted" value="{{saveButton}}" /> <input
    type="button" ng-click="isEditabel = false" id="backLink"
    class="btn btn-link btn-lg" value="Cancel">
</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.saveReleaseNotes = function(latestReleaseNotes,isEditabel) {
    $scope.backgroundWorking = true;
    $scope.saveButton = 'Updating...';
    $http({
        url: '/apps/'+$scope.app.id+'.json',
        method: "PUT",
        data: {
            releaseNotes: latestReleaseNotes,
            appBuildId:$scope.app.latestBuild.id
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.result == "success") {
            flash.showSuccess(data.message);
            $scope.isEditabel = false;
        } else {
            flash.showError(data.message);
            $scope.latestReleaseNotes = $scope.app.latestBuild.releaseNotes;
        }
        $scope.backgroundWorking = false;
        $scope.saveButton = 'Save';
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        flash.showError("Error occued while updating release notes");
        $scope.backgroundWorking = false;
        $scope.saveButton = 'Save';
    });
}
```

but model isEditable is not updated in view. I need hide `<div>` tag and show `<p>` tag on success.I'm trying by `$scope.isEditabel = false;` but it is not working.

Comment: Can you create a small fiddle to show us the issue?  I am  confused to why you mix and match between `isEditabel` and `$parent.isEditabel`

Comment: @Nix thanks for reply. when I removed all $parent then Edit link don't     work and other $parent I have removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is you are toggling between using `$parent.isEditable` and `isEditable.`  My first suggestion is to be consistent.  Idealy `isEditable` is contained within the scope that you are using it.  It seems a little odd to always be referencing "isEditable" of a parent.

If `isEditable` truly is contained within the parent you need to be careful about setting `$scope.isEditable = true`.  You can end up redeclaring it on the child scope.  I always suggest using functions like `setIsEditable(true)` and define that in the parent scope.

Trying to create a fiddle for you based on what you have given us.. but I think the below code would work.

---

```
//Parent scope
$scope.isEditabel = false;
$scope.setIsEditabel = function(value){
    $scope.isEditabel = value;
}
```

---

```
 <!-- updated html  -->

<div class="clearfix mr-b25 bdr-b">
    <h6 class="mr-tb20">Release Notes &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a ng-if="$parent.isEditabel == false" href="" ng-click="$parent.setIsEditabel(true)"
        class="f-14 semi-bold mr-l15"> Edit </a>
    </h6>
</div>
<p ng-show="!$parent.isEditabel" class="form-control-static f-14">{{latestReleaseNotes}} 
</p>


<div ng-show="$parent.isEditabel">
    <textarea ng-model="latestReleaseNotes" rows="3" columns="15"
        class="form-control" ng-disabled="formSubmitting">
     </textarea>
    <br /> 
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-r15" type="button"
        ng-click="$parent.saveReleaseNotes(latestReleaseNotes,$parent.isEditabel);$apply()"
        ng-disabled="formSubmitted" value="{{saveButton}}" /> <input
        type="button" ng-click="$parent.isEditabel = false" id="backLink"
        class="btn btn-link btn-lg" value="Cancel"/>
</div>
```

---

**the better solution(always debatable)***:
I created a `myModel` this isn't necessary but it does clean things up a bit, esp. if you ever have to have multiple editable things on the same page.

We dont have to worry about passing around isEditable to the save, we shouldn't have to worry about `apply.`  General suggestion is to make your html dumber..

```
//child scope
$scope.myModel = {
    latestReleaseNotes: latestReleaseNotes,
    isEditabel: false
}
$scope.saveReleaseNotes = function(){ 
   //do save 
   //we have everything we need on $scope (myModel, isEdiabel, etc.)
}
```

---

```
 <!-- updated html  -->

<div class="clearfix mr-b25 bdr-b">
    <h6 class="mr-tb20">Release Notes &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a ng-if="myModel.isEditabel == false" href="" ng-click="myModel.isEditabel = true"
        class="f-14 semi-bold mr-l15"> Edit </a>
    </h6>
</div>
<p ng-show="!myModel.isEditabel" class="form-control-static f-14">{{myModel.latestReleaseNotes}} 
</p>


<div ng-show="myModel.isEditabel">
    <textarea ng-model="myModel.latestReleaseNotes" rows="3" columns="15"
        class="form-control" ng-disabled="formSubmitting">
     </textarea>
    <br /> 
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-r15" type="button"
        ng-click="saveReleaseNotes(myModel);"
        ng-disabled="formSubmitted" value="{{saveButton}}" /> <input
        type="button" ng-click="myModel.isEditabel = false" id="backLink"
        class="btn btn-link btn-lg" value="Cancel"/>
</div>
```